# Difference between ~고도 and ~아도/어도/여도

Tags: grammar

Can you explain the differences between ~고도 and ~아도/어도/여도. Where can I use ~고도 instead of ~아도/어도/여도 and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite difficult to explain it in English, but let me show you some important points here.

-고도 is used to describe the same thing or person (or the same group). It is not used in imperative and suggestive sentences.

-어도/아도/여도 is used to talk about what is (or could be) against the listener/reader's usual expectation based on a fact or regarding a real/imaginary condition.

In a sentence, either "A1 + -고도 + B1" or "A2 + -어도/아도/여도 + B2" appears as a predicate or an attributive adjectival phrase.

---

-고도

(1) When A1 and B1 contain different adjectives, the adjectives refer to two qualities of a thing or person (or two qualities of a group). Please note that one quality does *not have to* be contrary to the other.

Examples:

> - 이 종은 슬프고도 맑은 소리를 낸다. (The phrase, "at once A1 (saddening) and B1 (clear)," describes the sound of "this" bell.)
> - 그 옷차림은 멋지고도 말끔했다. (The predicate, "was A1 (nice) and also B1 (neat)," describes how a person dressed.)

(2) When A1 contains an verb, A1 precedes B1 in terms of relative tense. In other words, B1 refers to a more future state or action than A1. In this regard, -었- and -겠- cannot be attached to -고도.

Examples with rough translations:

> - 이 피자는 둘이 먹고도 남았어요. (This pizza was eaten by two and (some of it was) left over.)
> - 이 피자는 둘이 먹고도 남을 것이다. (Even if this pizza is/were eaten by two, (some of) it will/would be left over.)
> - 그때는 걔가 집에 돌아오고도 남을 시간이었다. (That was when she/he had already come back home.)
> - 걔는 공부를 열심히 하고도 입학시험에 떨어졌다. (She/he (had) worked hard but failed to pass the entrance exam.)
> - 걔는 집에 도착하고도 나한테 전화하지 않을걸. (She/he will not phone me even when she/he gets home, I think.)

Other examples:

> - 너는 그러고도 네게 잘못이 없다고 말하니?
> - 우리는 서로를 사랑하고도 서로에게 사랑한다고 하지 못했다.
> - 그 남자는 내 연필을 쓰고도 쓰지 않은 척했다.
> - 얘야, 음식을 그렇게 많이 먹고도 괜찮겠니?
> - 그자는 돈을 많이 벌고도 남에게 동정을 베풀지 않았다.
> - 내 친구는 그렇게 슬픈 영화를 보고도 울지 않는다.
> - 네가 그러고도 사람이냐?
> - 소매치기 때문에 그렇게 고생하고도 또 해외여행을 가고 싶니?

---

-어도/아도/여도

(1) When A2 and B2 contain different adjectives, the adjectives refer to two qualities. One quality is contrasted with the other that is not usually expected. You do *not have to* describe the same thing or person.

Examples:

> - 수입은 적어도 마음은 풍족하다. ((내) 수입 vs. (내) 마음.)
> - 걔는 겉모습은 그래도 마음은 착해. (걔의 겉모습 vs. 걔 마음.)
> - 그자는 키는 작아도 힘은 세다. (그자의 키 vs. 그자의 힘.)
> - 박 군은 나이가 어려도 영특한 사람이다. (박 군 is 나이가 어리다 but 영특하다.)

(2) When A2 does not contain an adjective or when B2 does not, B2 mentions what is (or could be) against the listener/reader's usual expectation regarding A2 (unrealistic or not). You should use -었- and -겠- when they are needed.

Examples with rough translations:

> - 여기를 지나간다고? 죽어도 안 된다! (I will not let you pass by here even if I die!)
> - (제가) 이 일은 죽어도 잊지 않을게요. (I will not forget this even if I die.)
> - 노래를 잘 못해도 괜찮아요. ((I am) fine even if (you are) not that good at singing.)
> - 제가 아무리 졸라도 걔는 꿈쩍도 안 해요. (No matter how much I pester her/him, she/he does not budge at all.)
> - 무슨 일이 있어도 이 임무를 완수하여야 한다. (No matter what happens, (we/I) need to complete this mission.)
> - 걔는 목이 아파도 노래를 부른다. (She/he sings (or is singing) even though/when her/his throat hurts.)
> - 아무리 바빠도 식사는 꼭 챙겨 드세요. (However busy you are, do not skip meals.)

Other examples:

> - 보일러를 켜도 찬물만 나와요.
> - 말만 통한다면 10살 연상이어도 상관없어요.
> - 저는 물만 마셔도 살이 쪄요.
> - 호랑이에게 물려 가도 정신만 차리면 산다.
> - 내일 비가 와도 소풍 갈 거예요?
> - 나라면 비가 왔어도 나들이를 갔을 것이다.
> - 육체는 죽었어도 혼은 아직 살아 있다.
> - 여기 앉아도 돼요?
> - 가도 가도 끝이 없네요. (Here, the "A2 + -아도 + A2 + -아도 + B2" construction was used to emphasize "A2 + -아도".)
> - 걔가 바로 병원에만 갔어도 살았을 텐데.

Answer (score 0):

I feel ~고도 has a reversing sense in the middle of the sentence.

Let me clarify.
You use ~고도 attached to a verb.
For example, 사랑하고도 means "even if you loved" to me.
It feels more like "even AFTER you loved" or "even though you loved"

나는 사랑하고도 사랑한다 말할 수 없었다.
I just added a subject for the sake of English translation.
Even AFTER I loved (someone), I couldn't say I loved (someone).

As you see here, I have a negative sentence after "사랑하고도".
This is the "reversing sense" I said in the beginning.

This applies the other way around, too.

그녀는 물어보지 않고도 이해할 수 있었다.
Even AFTER she didn't ask (something), she could understand it.
The proper translation for this would be as follows:
She could understand it without asking.

As you see, the negative sense of ~하지 않고도 is followed by something positive.
This is another "reversing sense" I mentioned above.

In a casual conversation, ~하지 않고도 ~~할 수 있다 is used quite often.

However, the other way ~하고도 ~할 수 없다. sounds more of a written language than spoken one. Also, the latter one even sounds somewhat lyrical or poetic.

Answer (score 0):

고도 does not follow 아도 in some usages :

**Adjective** 그는 작아도 기운은 세다 He is short but strong

작고도 is not fine.

**Present** 닦아도 얼룩이 지워지지 않는다. Even though I clean, how
dirty it is

닦고도 얼룩이 지워지지 않았다 may be possible.

닦고도 얼룩이 지워지지 않는다 is weird to me.

닦고도, 지워지지 않니 ? Even though you clean, it is still dirty ?

**Future** 먹어도 괜찮아 Now, I allow that you would eat.

먹고도 괜찮아 When I ate it, it is Okay.

먹고도 괜찮아 ? When you ate it, it is Okay ?